# pass array to $this->beginWidget use in Header from controller?

Tags: php, yii

**I am using Widget  in my Header layout.**

In My controller .I have set following variables:

```
public $testVal="testing";
```

I have created a widget in YII and I use it in **my Header layout**:

```
<?php  $this->beginWidget('CountryWithCityWidget'); $this->endWidget();?>
```

My widget Code is:

```
<?php
class CountryWithCityWidget extends CWidget
{
public $countryList;
public $cityList;

 public function init()
{

    print_r($testVal);// I need $testVal testing here from view ***How ????***
    echo "==============================";
    die;


    parent::init();
}

public function run()
{
     $this->render('countryWithCityWidget',array('countryList' => $this->countryList,'locationDetailList'=>$this->cityList));
}
}
?>
```

In view I will get it like  `$this->testVal`  and then from view I want to send $testVal to widget where I am using it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you get solution of it?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$this->widget('CountryWithCityWidget', array(
    'testVal' => $testVal
));
```

and add a property `testVal` to your widget class. Also pass your `$testVal` var to your view.

[for further reading](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/de/basics.view#widget)

Comment: What do you mean with "header"? Is this a view part in your layout view?

Comment: That's a bit tricky. See [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4473-how-to-pass-variable-to-a-layout/).